# Best way to integrate picasa in Android app using OAuth2.0

Tags: android, picasa

i am writing a application which need to access picasa from android app. I wanna use the OAuth2.0 for the autherization.

Saw documentations but i am confused, with the using google-api-java-client1.10.3.jar
Please suggest how to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this android module for oauth2.0 https://github.com/Hafiz-Waleed-Hussain/EasySocial